# How to load mongodb script file while prompting for password?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB database that requires a password while also loading and running a script file on the database. I want to do it all from the command line and have the mongo shell exit afterwards. My problem is that I cannot do both at the same time, e.g.

```
$ mongo example.com:10023/database -u username -p script.js
```

The above command will think that `script.js` is actually my password, which it of cause isn't. I want it to actually prompt me for my password after I enter the command.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the arguments around so that `script.js` does not follow your password parameter.

`$mongo example.com:10023/database script.js -u username -p`

Comment: So freaking simple. And yet I never thought about moving the arguments around. Why? Because "<file.js> .. Must be the last option specified.". Thanks!